# Inject collection name in @Document from spring data mongodb in using a property from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'd like to name my collection name from a Mongo Collection in using a property from application.yml.

For instance, if i got that file :
application.yml

```
spring.data.mongodb.person-collection: character
```

And I'd like to inject that property in that Entity:

```
@Document(collection = "@Value('spring.data.mongodb.person-collection')")
public class PersonEntity {
    ...
}
```

I'd like to use that property because i've many environment, who use the same database. I'd like to isolate some collections in function of the environment.

Do you have any idea how I can resolve that ?

(I tried with SpEL but I couldn't resolve that problem).

Edit :

I tried to make a workaround in using another bean to inject my property

```
@Component
public class PersonRepositoryCustom {

private static String collectionName;

/**
 * @return the collectionName
 */
public static String getCollectionName() {
    return collectionName;
}

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.person-collection:person}")
public void setCollectionName(String collectionNameVariable) {
    collectionName = collectionNameVariable;
}

}
```

So I changed my document annotation by :

```
@Document(collection = "#{@T(persistence.mongodb.repositories.PersonRepositoryCustom).getCollectionName()}")
```

SO i got that message

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:135) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:61) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:33) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpressions(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:121) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseTemplate(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:62) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:49) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.detectExpression(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:255) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:80) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:90) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:39) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:248) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:191) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:73) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:149) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:123) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
... 22 more
```

I tried it in another way, in using a bean directly :

```
package persistence.mongodb.repositories;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PersonRepositoryCustom {

private static String collectionName;

/**
 * @return the collectionName
 */
public String getCollectionName() {
    return collectionName;
}

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.person-collection:person}")
public void setCollectionName(String collectionNameVariable) {
    collectionName = collectionNameVariable;
}

}
```

So i updated my document annotation with the following :

```
@Document(collection = "#{@personRepositoryCustom.getCollectionName()}")
```

And i got that message :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean  'personRepositoryCustom'
```

Comment: Change `@Document(collection = "#{@personRepositoryCustom.getCollectionName()}")` to `@Document(collection = "#{personRepositoryCustom.getCollectionName()}")`

Comment: Fot `T() operator` getCollectionName must be `static`

Comment: This can be easily achieved with the help of a config class, where we read data from the properties file and pass it to the entity class. For step-by-step implementation, please refer to https://paulsofts.com/how-to-inject-collection-name-in-document-from-properties-file-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a way to resolve that in using a part of the answer given by @Valijon and another part from another post on stackoverflow

```
package persistence.mongodb.repositories;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PersonRepositoryCustom {

private static String collectionName;

/**
 * @return the collectionName
 */
public static String getCollectionName() {
    return collectionName;
}

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.person-collection:person}")
public void setCollectionName(String collectionNameVariable) {
    collectionName = collectionNameVariable;
}

}

@Document(collection = "#{T(mongodb.repositories.PersonRepositoryCustom).getCollectionName() }")
public class PersonEntity { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

**In SpEL, using a bean, be sure to use `@` before the bean name. This is relevant because if it is missing, SpEL will look for a property of that name instead of a bean. I lost some time before figuring this out.
The answer of @Valijon and @user3460409 are close to correct, but neither talks about the use of `@`, instead talking about the `T` operator.**

Create a class that has a field annotated with the `@Value` annotation, getting the property from the file. A bean for this class should be created, in this example I use `@Component` for bean auto-generation.

```
@Component
class Constants {
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.person-collection}")
    private String personCollectionName;

    public String getPersonCollectionName() {
        return this.personCollectionName;
    }
}
```

Next, in your actual entity class, use SpEL (Spring Expression Language) to fetch the value from the bean of the created class (by default the bean name is the lowercase class name).

```
@Document(collection = "#{@constants.personCollectionName}")
public class PersonEntity {
    ...
}
```

**Again, notice the `@` before the bean name.**

Answer (score 0):

You may use SpEL (It works)

1. Use `@Component` class to get `@Value` and use SpEL

---

```
@Component
public class CustomMongoCollection {

    @Value("spring.data.mongodb.person-collection")
    private String person;

    public void getCollectionName(String coll) {
        if ("person".equals(coll)) {
            return person;
        } else {
            //setup here
        }
    }
}

@Document(collection = "#{customMongoCollection.getCollectionName('person')}")
public class PersonEntity {

}
```

**Note:** I had problems during unit testing

---

2. Use 'T' operator

   > The special 'T' operator can be used to specify an instance of java.lang.Class (the 'type'). Static methods are invoked using this operator as well. The StandardEvaluationContext uses a TypeLocator to find types and the StandardTypeLocator (which can be replaced) is built with an understanding of the java.lang package. This means T() references to types within java.lang do not need to be fully qualified, but all other type references must be.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html

```
#{T(your.package.CustomMongoCollection).getCollectionName('person')}
```

**Note:** Now CustomMongoCollection.getCollectionName is `static` method.

Comment: @SlimSoltaniDridi try to remove `@` from SPEL

Comment: Your second point resolved my problem. Thanks a lot. I created another answer to give the final result.